# Can I share or synchronized Google account from user 0 (owner) to user Guest in android phone?

Tags: android, adb, multiple-users

I am making small tool to control android phone with ADB command.
I use `adb shell pm create-user --guest guestUser` to create Guest user (this way to change android ID without factory reset or root). But Guest user or other user do not auto login my Google account that working in User 0 (Owner), it make me login Google account again after create any User. Is there any way to share or synchronized Google account between multiple User?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As far as I know the user profiles are separated from each other. So the only way I see would be adding the Google user account as profile to the guest user, but most likely that would require to log on on the device as that user as Google authentication can only be done by a user in an interactive way.